# Can Google Docs for Android work Offline?

Tags: offline, google-drive, productivity

I am intending to get probably the Asus Eee Pad Transformer soon. I am looking at the apps I need. I am thinking of getting just the non 3G version and wonder if the lack of 3G/Internet connectivity will affect my use of applications like Google Docs. Perhaps I need to look at a non-cloud based app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Google Docs on Android has no offline cache at the moment.** <sup>[Source](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=63419faeb0798184&hl=en)</sup>

The [Browser version has this functionality](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1628469). I hope the Android App get's offline docs too, that would be awesome. :)

Comment: That page says right at the beginning "Keep in mind that offline access is only available in Chrome."

Comment: Time flies, and the second link already included how to turn offline access on/off on Android :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

I just put my phone into Airplane mode, and tapped the "Docs" icon that I happened to have on my home screen.  It showed me a list of my docs!  So far, so good.

I then tapped one of the docs, and saw a frowny face that said something like "Sorry, can't access this document because I don't have a connection to the Internet".